# Cannot simulate code in Tinkercad

Tags: arduino, motor

[image]

Too much load for Arduino to handle? I was hoping I could reduce the number of slots being used by running two motors for the same side wheels of a robot. I am mainly referring to the right and bottom 4 motors, 2 on each output. A circuit error started coming up after I did that.

Comment: no, probably not

Comment: `2 on each output` ... doesn't look like that

Comment: not too much load for the Arduino, but perhaps for the USB feed, depending on the type of motor. Consider using a separate power supply for the motors.